# add listener or timer to console

Tags: java

Is it possible to add a loop timer to the console as calling updateTime() every 100ms?

I found `sequencer.addMetaEventListener(this);` is probably for MIDI or audio only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using a `java.util.Timer`([API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)).

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm) site gives multiple examples of the use of the `Timer` class.

Comment: Good tip, but have another problem with the repeat timer, it use quite a large amount of memory.